# Altair: Javascript error prevents chart display

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, firefox, altair

I am starting to use Altair and at the moment I am just trying to replicate what is done here: https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/filled_step_chart.html .

I have just tried to run that code on my Mac (OS 10.14.6) with python 3.6 (tried also with python3.8) in Jupyter in Mozilla Firefox 74.0.1 (64-bit) and I get this error as output:

> Javascript error adding output!
>
> TypeError: document.currentScript is null
>
> See your browser Javascript console for more details.

This is what I see, also checking the Console's errors:

[image: code and error in Jupyter]

I have tried to trouble shoot following the instructions on the Altair's pages: https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/troubleshooting.html#chart-does-not-display-at-all, but I would need more guidance.

Thank you for your help in advance.

---

**Update 15 April 2020:**

After trying @jakevdp's workaround (https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/display_frontends.html#displaying-in-the-jupyter-notebook), adding the line

```
alt.renderers.enable('notebook')
```

I don't see anymore that error in Jupyter nor in the Console, however, the plot doesn't show up:
[image: no output despite no errors]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in Altair's HTML renderer; please report it at http://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues.

As a workaround, you should be able to use the vega nbextension, as described here: https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/display_frontends.html#displaying-in-the-jupyter-notebook

Comment: Thank you @jakevdp, I've tried your workaround but it didn't fully work. I've updated my question to explain better what's the new issue.

Comment: Did you follow all the instructions at the link? In particular, did you install the vega notebook extension before trying to use it by adding the ``renderers.enable`` line?

Comment: Yes, @jakevdp, I did. To make sure I have also started a fresh environment and installed all the required modules. The issue is still there.

Comment: Just ran into this same issue, and doing `jupyter nbextension install --sys-prefix --py vega` in Anaconda prompt, as described in the second link in this answer, worked for me.